# How to get the difference of two COUNT() operations in Apache pig?

Tags: apache-pig

I want to reduce the amount of processing by taking the difference of COUNT() operations.
For example, if conditionA is if a field is NOT NULL, then conditionB is if a field is NULL.
I want to count the total items in the data and subtract the count of items with conditionA in order to get the counts of conditionB.
Essentially, the mathematical equation is just conditionB = total - conditionA.

```
filterByTime = FILTER data BY timestamp >= 0;
filterByTimeGroup = GROUP filterByTime ALL;
filterByTimeCount = FOREACH filterByTimeGroup GENERATE COUNT(filterByTime);

filterByConditionA = FILTER filterByTime BY conditionA IS NOT NULL;
filterByConditionAGroup = GROUP filterByConditionA ALL;
filterByConditionACount = FOREACH filterByConditionAGroup GENERATE COUNT(filterByConditionA);

filterByConditionB = filterByTimeCount - filterByConditionACount;
```

How would I do this in Apache Pig? Would I need to use the SPLIT operator and count from those groups instead?

Answer (score 0):

Count where conditionA is null. Note this assumes that there are no other subsets based on a different filter.

```
filterByConditionB = FILTER data BY (conditionA IS NULL AND timestamp >= 0);
filterByConditionBGroup = GROUP filterByConditionB ALL;
filterByConditionNCount = FOREACH filterByConditionBGroup GENERATE COUNT(filterByConditionB);
```